# Get Pointer Id only , using Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

this returns an object. I just want to get the id. I will use it for a query

```
 var q= new Parse.Query("Comments");
q.find({
    success: function (results) {
        for (var i=0; i< results.length;i++) {
            console.log(results[i].get("user_id"));
   } 
   });
```

Comment: i actually found it out by exploring,  i've used to access just the id 
    results[i].get("user_id").id

Comment: @AKMnlc then post that as answer to close this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i actually found it out by exploring, i've used to access just the id

```
results[i].get("user_id").id
```